# streaming data through mqtt to aws IoT with acknowledgement mechanism

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, real-time-data

I am trying to send chunks of a data by using MQTT to aws IoT and by rule engine, the data will be streamed to a web app in real time (or near to real time )manner.

I am trying to find a way by which I can get some kind of acknowledgement. the role of acknowledgement is important for my use case as I am trying to send some kind of medical equipment data (lets say blood pressure data during operation).

thus, In a nut shell, I need a quickest way to transfer data(just like MQTT) between the device and AWS IoT which should have some kind acknowledgement mechanism. 

Also I would like to add that ,'if suppose the device or web server could not get the message sent by MQTT due to some internet issues, then it will be lost right. I need to add some sort of mechanism by which the mqtt messages could be buffered and queued for some time so that once the device or web app comes online it can get the queued data. I also know that there is something called device shadow but we have thought using it differently. can you suggest about it ?'

I am sure that some of you have faced this problem and also found an alternate of MQTT in data transferring to AWS IoT. 
Kindly share your thoughts. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can use the MQTT `QOS 1` capability when publishing a message to ensure you get an acknowledgment back. Is that all you are asking? Please be aware that the AWS IoT service isn't covered by the AWS HIPAA compliance program at this time.

Comment: hi Mark, can you provide some URLs to read about it where I can read better about QOS1 implementation with aws IoT ? meanwhile I will also search about it from my side. thanks for suggestion. :)

Comment: there is one more thing i forgot to add, if suppose the device or web server could not get the message sent by MQTT due to some internet issue, then it will be lost right . I need to add some sort of mechanism by which the mqtt messages could be buffered and queued for some time so that once the device or web app comes online it can get the new data. I also know that there is something called device shadow but we have thought using it differently. can you suggest about it ?